# Алгоритм построения набора ломаных из набора отрезков

Tags: алгоритм, геометрия

Добрый день, может кто подскажет алгоритм сбора ломаных из набора отрезков?
Дано: список отрезков с указанием на две точки, из набора надо собрать какое-то количество ломаных (чаще всего замкнутые) по совпадению у двух отрезков двух точек. Может как-то надо модифицировать добавление отрезков в список для облегчения задачи?
Единственное что я представляю: выбирать отрезок из списка и добавлять в текущую кривую, потом для всех оставшихся отрезков из списка искать следующий по совпадению с одной из точек, если не найдено, то добавлять новую кривую для первого отрезка из оставшегося списка. Но многовато операций, есть что-то лучше?

Comment: На первый взгляд, только поиск ускорить, сделав хэш-таблицу по точкам отрезков с разрешением коллизий цепочками. Там хранить пары (точка, адрес-отрезка-в-списке). А отрезки в списке помечать номером кривой (это чтобы не зациклиться).

Сходу, как-то так.

Comment: Я бы наверное наборы отсортировал, что сократило бы перебор до соседних элементов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создаем по отрезкам матрицу смежности. В цикле по вершинам определяем к какой компоненте графа относится каждая вершина, совершая обход для каждой из ранее не пройденных вершин. [Тут](http://neerc.secna.ru/Algor/algo_base_graph_intr.html) решение.

Оптимальность здесь на ваш вкус. Можно вероятно и оптимальнее, но без обхода никак, и без поиска вершин среди других отрезков тоже. имхо, годный вариант.